# angular HttpClientModule get changes input url?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular service that calls a nodejs server for data like this:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
  }

  getPersonData(): Observable<person[]> {
    //return this.http.get<person[]>('/assets/data/people.json');
    return this.http.get<person[]>("127.0.0.1:3000/people");
  }
```

but in the browser I get a not found error for http://127.0.0.1:4200/127.0.0.1:3000/people

instead of:
127.0.0.1:3000/people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you specify `http://` or `https://`

```js
this.http.get<person[]>("https://127.0.0.1:3000/people")
```

Comment: thank you, that seemed to be the issue

Comment: Awesome! That’s good to hear. If that solved your issue, please mark the answer as accepted